# How to stop my images being seen from direct URL access?

Tags: php, image, url

I have a website in PHP (e.g. xyz.com). It is on my local server. And all the images used in the website are stored in xyz/images. When somebody types my website name with the folder name ("images") he can see all the images. How to prevent that?

Note: I have used HTML, PHP, JQuery and CSS to make my website. I don't have htaccess file.

Comment: you can create a htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty file index.php inside your "images" folder.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Should I apply this method to other folders also - "js", "style" and "includes"?

Comment: Yes you can do the same for any other folder.